# VBA alternative to Application.Quotient that includes decimals

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to use `Application.AverageIfs` and I need to divide the answer by 3. I tried this way:

```
Range("C1:C676") = (Application.IfError(Application.AverageIfs(Sheets(modelName).Range("R:R"....
                    Sheets(modelName).Range("U:U"), "OGV"), "0") / 3)
```

and also without the brackets round the first `application` and the final `3` but this gives a type mismatch error.

Nesting it within `Application.Quotient` works but it only gives the integer part of the answer and I need the decimal as well. Is there a decimal-friendly alternative? I would prefer to continue to use the `application` syntax rather than putting `range().formula = "=averageifs(` if its possible.

**Edit:** after J.Fox's suggestion I have broken the formula parts into variables. The problem seems to be the `criZFrom` and `criZTo` variables which use a range in a separate sheet as criteria. The formula works fine if I replace these variables with `"1"` and `"2"` respectively. The code is now:

```
Set rng = Sheets(wsName).Range("C1:C676")
    Set avgCol = Sheets(modelName).Range("M:M")
    Set colZFrom = Sheets(modelName).Range("G:G")
    Set criZFrom = Sheets(wsName).Range("A1:A676")
    Set colZTo = Sheets(modelName).Range("H:H")
    Set criZTo = Sheets(wsName).Range("B1:B676")
    Set colTime = Sheets(modelName).Range("V:V")
    Set colVType = Sheets(modelName).Range("U:U")

    criVType = "OGV"
    criAM = "AM"

        Range("A1:A676").Formula = "=roundup(row()/26,0)"

        Range("B1:B676").Formula = "=if(mod(row(),26)=0,26,mod(row(),26))"

            rng = Application.AverageIfs(avgCol, colZFrom, criZFrom, colZTo, criZTo, colTime, criAM, colVType, criVType) / 3
```

Here is some sample data:

from `sheets(modelName)`, this has the data that I am trying to average and most of the criteria ranges: [image]

From `sheets(wsName)`, this has the criteria for the problem variables and is where I want the result to appear (in column C): [image]

Comment: What error are you getting in the edited code and on what line? Also where are you using `criZFrom` and `criZTo`? I don't see them in the edited code other than where they're defined. Are all the variables `Dim`'d as ranges?

Comment: Argh I copied it after I tried it using the 1 and 2 hard coded. I've edited it now. The error is `run-tim error 13: type mismatch` THe error is on the `rng = Application.AverageIfs(` if i use the variables. If i hard code the 1 or 2 in place (coming from columns G and H) the error goes away and the formula works. The problem variables are `Dim`d as ranges yes. Columns G and H in the first sheet need to accord with Columns A and B in the second sheet. I only get the error if i have the `/ 3` after the main formula. if I remove this, the formula calculates correctly

Comment: Ahh, I think I see the problem now. I edited my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you're missing a closing parenthesis after `"OGV")` to close out the `AverageIfs` function, i.e.:

```
Range("C1:C676") = Application.IfError(Application.AverageIfs(Sheets(modelName).Range("R:R", Sheets(modelName).Range("U:U"), "OGV")), 0) / 3
```

Also, not sure if `....` was just for on here or in your code, but you'd want to use `_` instead, as in:

```
Range("C1:C676") = _ 
Application.IfError(Application.AverageIfs(Sheets(modelName).Range("R:R", _
Sheets(modelName).Range("U:U"), "OGV")), 0) / 3
```

**Edit:** If you're still getting an error, I suggest breaking up your formula into component parts and assigning each part to a variable so you can troubleshoot exactly where the issue is, like so:

```
Sub test()
Dim rng As Range, col1 As Range, col2 As Range, str As String, modelName As String

modelName = "Sheet1"

Set rng = Range("C1:C676")
Set col1 = Sheets(modelName).Columns(18)
Set col2 = Sheets(modelName).Columns(21)
str = "OGV"

rng = Application.IfError(Application.AverageIfs(col1, col2, str), 0) / 3

End Sub
```

Can we see some sample data? It might be an issue of what order the arguments are being passed for the `AverageIfs` function.

**Edit 2:** I think I might see what the problem is. You're using the `AverageIfs` function with the intention of validating each line separately based on the specific criteria for each line by using a range for Arg3 and Arg5 instead of single values, which `AverageIfs` doesn't like. Criteria for `Ifs` functions will always need to be a single value instead of a range of values. Instead, I think you would need to iterate each line separately using a loop, like this:

```
Set avgCol = Sheets(modelName).Range("M:M")
Set colZFrom = Sheets(modelName).Range("G:G")
Set colZTo = Sheets(modelName).Range("H:H")
Set colTime = Sheets(modelName).Range("V:V")
Set colVType = Sheets(modelName).Range("U:U")

criVType = "OGV"
criAM = "AM"

Range("A1:A676").Formula = "=roundup(row()/26,0)"
Range("B1:B676").Formula = "=if(mod(row(),26)=0,26,mod(row(),26))"

Dim x as Long
Dim t as Variant

For x = 1 To 676
    Set criZFrom = Sheets(wsName).Range("A" & x)
    Set criZTo = Sheets(wsName).Range("B" & x)
    Set Rng = Sheets(wsName).Range("C" & x)

    t = Application.WorksheetFunction.AverageIfs(avgCol, colZFrom, criZFrom.Value, colZTo, criZTo.Value, colTime, criAM, colVType, criVType)
    t = CDbl(t / 3)
    Rng.Value = t
Next x
```

Comment: ah sorry, the `....` was there because the full formula is so long I thought I would shorten it for readability. The full code does use `_` as you suggest. If I add the parenthesis as suggested it gives `compile error: expected: end of statement`.

Comment: No worries. I added a potential solution as an edit.

Comment: ok thanks, I'll try that. So should just adding `/ 3` after the main formula work then?

Comment: I have narrowed the problem down and edited my original question following your helpful suggestions, and added some sample data.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm still getting a type mismatch error after the Edit 2 suggestion. Even though when you hover over `criZFrom.Value` and it shows `1`. It just doesn't like the ` / 3` after as it works without. I wondered if it was to do with `Dim`ing the `rng` variable (currently as range) to handle decimals (i.e. as double) but after some tests it seems not.

Comment: That's crazy! I can't imagine why the / 3 would make it not work. I just made another edit (essentially defining a `Variant` and assigning the value there), see how that works.

Comment: Yes this works! thanks for your help. what is the `CDbl` bit, is this like assigning a variable to the answer on the fly?

Comment: I'm glad that worked! `CDbl` is probably not even necessary here but I didn't want to take any chances. The `CDbl` just ensures that the results of `t / 3` are stored in `t` as a Double variable type to preserve decimal values. I wouldn't *think* that it would store as something without a decimal since it's `Dim`'d as `Variant` but you never know.